# Have an Image Center in the Global Window / Viewport when clicked (JS or CSS)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, click, viewport

I'd like to have it when I click an image that it centers in the viewport (like a lightbox effect).

I've set up a pen here http://codepen.io/emilychews/pen/OpXKGd and tried work out the best way to do this but I seem to have hit a wall.

I've included multiple elements in the demo because I'd like it so it uses the window as it's centering container, not just the parent element.  I'll be using this on a wordpress site so saying just add a wrapper isn't viable for me.

Also if you look at the demo, at the moment the elements scale up smoothly and i'd like to have it align centrally in the window object as part of the transition when it scales up.

I appreciate this may only be possible with JS / jQuery and i have included some in my example.

My code for quick reference is:

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="holder image1">Image 1</div>
  <div class="holder image2">Image 2</div>
  <div class="holder image3">Image 3</div>
  <div class="holder image4">Image 4</div>
  <div class="holder image5">Image 5</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.holder {
width: 20vw;
height: 400px;
background: red;
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
margin-bottom: 5px;
transition: all .75s ease-out;
}

// ======== THIS IS THE CLASS THAT IS ADDED WITH JQUERY
.fullsize {
background: blue;
z-index: 2;
position: relative;
transform: scale(1.75);
transform-origin: center center;
transition: all .75s ease-out;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready (function(){

  $('.holder').click(function() {

      $( this ).toggleClass('fullsize');
      $( this ).css('z-index', '+=1');

  });

});
```

Any help / solution would be amazing.

Emily :)

Comment: Are you set on only using CSS or if we can get there with JQuery is that ok?

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're looking for is to set a `left` property on the full size image. Note that you will also need to use `position: absolute` in order to offset each element by the same amount (centralising them).

```
.fullsize {
  position: absolute;
  left: 40vw;
}
```

I've created an updated CodePen showcasing this [here](http://codepen.io/Obsidian-Age/pen/bqwbVX).

Note that you also may want to give them a higher z-index, as the .fullsize elements are sometimes obscured behind the regular images.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what I was looking for.  That just realigns it in it's containing element.  I want it centered in the window object so wherever the image is on the screen it both enlarges and centers itself in the window.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It's a little jumpy and needs some fiddling, but it gives you what you want.

Change .holder to:

```
.holder {
width: 20vw;
height: 100px;
background: red;
position: static;
display: inline-block;
margin-bottom: 5px;
transition: all .75s ease-out;
 z-index:0;
  transform-origin: top left;
}
```

Change .fullsize to:

```
.holder.fullsize {
background: blue;
z-index: 200;
transform: scale(1.75);
transition: all .75s ease-out;
  position:absolute;  
}
```

and change your JQuery to

```
$(document).ready (function(){

  $('.holder').click(function() {
    var $scaleFactor = 1.75;
      $( this ).toggleClass('fullsize');
    var $winWidth = $(window).width();
    var $myWidth = $(this).width();
    var $newWidth = $myWidth*$scaleFactor;
    var $left = $winWidth/2-$newWidth/2;
    $(".holder").text($left);
    $(this).animate({    
      left:$left+"px"
    },200);

  });

});
```

Setting the scaling in the JQuery instead might give you a smoother transition.